# What happens after selfdestruct is called?

Tags: solidity, remix, ropsten, selfdestruct

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf825d3b3d06a4b46379a3c276df7f26abd055463

After `selfdestruct` call was made, all the balance was transferred to the deployer of the contract. Why are withdraw requests still being processed?

Comment: Interesting find. Good question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: After the [Constantinople fork](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1013), a new [opcode CREATE2](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014) allows to redeploy a previously seldestructed contract. So the assertion that funds remains locked foreverd doesn't apply in that case.

---

Previous answer follows:

After a contract calls `selfdestruct`, the code and storage associated with the contract are removed from the Ethereum's World State.

Transactions after that point will behave as if the address were an externally owned account, i.e. transaction will be accepted, no processing will be done, and the transaction status will be success.

Transactions will do nothing, but you still have to pay the transaction fee. You can even transfer ether. It will be locked forever or until someone finds one of the private keys associated with that address.

Comment: For anyone wondering if contracts actually do receive funds after they self-destruct, they do. The last transaction on that contract was to verify this answer.

Comment: Actually, nowadays it is possible in some cases to resurrect selfdestructed smart contract, even with different byte: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x7973d5166b9526b9e4e63595293d6b895d2d4fe3#code

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov You are correct. The answer predates CREATE2 opcode that allow redeploy into an existing address. I'll add a note to reflect the new behavior.

Comment: @Ismael: I would assume this would help developers greatly. But for users, I would imagine this would negatively affect their trust when interacting with smart contracts.  For a large, multi-layered, set of contracts. A contract could be self destructed and then redployed at whim by the owners, and the users would have to keeptrack of such an event for every single contract in the set.

Comment: @VigneshKarthikeyan I understand your concern, it is an issue that was already discussed. It was already possible for a contract to change its behavior after deployment using DELEGATECALL opcode if you deploy a new library.

Comment: @Ismael I understand what you're saying. It still doesn't sit well because of the semantics of said opcode; DELEGATECALL, sure, it's in the name. but what about a SELFDESTRUCT means it can be reversed.

Comment: @VigneshKarthikeyan It was discussed previously on several places like https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/potential-security-implications-of-create2-eip-1014/2614/2 or https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/aosaly/create2_eip_vulnerability_questions/. I think it is a bit too late to complain since it has been more than 6 months since it was deployed to mainnet. You can raise your concerns in the social media to alert other Ethereum users.

Comment: @Ismael. Thanks for the link. The nice part is that it's never too late to complain, I'm just not doing it at the right place. :)

Comment: But you have to create the contract with this new opcode in the first place. It won't work if the address was generated with the original CREATE opcode.